# Can't archive with simulator scheme within Xcode, but can do it using xcodebuild in command line. Why?

Tags: xcode, build, archive, command-line-tool

In Xcode, if I choose a simulator in the project navigator, **Archive** is greyed out in the **Product** menu.

But if I do it on the command line, it succeeds.

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme MySDK -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=6021D2E2-54B8-4641-9EA4-3673D1C665D1' SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

Why is archiving for a simulator not allowed within Xcode but allowed with xcodebuild on the command line?